# Android Socket-ready detection?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm programming an Android application allows to send messages between devices which are connected in the same local network. I've finished the socket programming part, each device can be a server or a client, one client only allow to connect with one server at a time (and vice versa). The problem is I need to know the IP address of the server I want to connect, then input it by hand on the client side.

I'm trying to establish a feature like in Multiplayer mode of game: you press "Show" button, and all the hosts (in my app they are the servers) which are avaiable will be displayed, then I can choose the host I want. But I have no idea how to achieve it, or where to start.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also create a `DatagramSocket` which will be used for broadcasting, on a different port, and every device that wants to be an `Server` should broadcast a packet with it's ip. You should look at [All about Datagrams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html) altough it does not contain an example of broadcast. For example to send a broadcast you should take a look at the following code :

```
DatagramSocket mServerSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
InetAddress  broadcastAddress=InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
byte[] data=new byte[1024];
data="your_data_string_example".getBytes();
DatagramPacket packet=new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                            sendData.length,broadcastAddress,PORT);
mServerSocket.setBroadcast(true);
mServerSocket.send(packet);
```

Comment: Thank for your quick and great answer. I made it work now. Only one little problem that the group ip should start with 224 (like mine is 224.2.72.0). I'm not strong about network programming so I don't understand this (something about not a multicast address). I will give it a look after I finish this application.